# Mounting a projector screen

Tags: home-theater

I'm looking into mounting a motorized projector screen in my home theater room.  I measured that the screen needs to be approximately 120" diagonal, so I'm looking into buying one of:

- [Elite Screens Spectrum Electric Budget Projection Screen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000Q87LM6)
- [FAVI 16:9/120-Inch Electric Projector Screen (HD-120)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0026DTP2S)

The problem is that I cannot mount the screen flush with the wall.  This is because the screen will be above my fireplace and due to the height of the picture, it'll need to come down in front of the mantle and cannot sit on top of the mantle.  In other words, the screen will need to descend approximately 8" off the wall.

Does anyone have any experience doing something like that, or any advice on how I could go about accomplishing it?

Judging from the specs the screen would weigh approximately 30 lbs, and since the chimney and flue is behind it, I would be nervous to try supporting the screen from the middle of its base, and ideally would only want to put supports from the sides.

Finally, the ceiling for the room is high and vaulted, so I'm not sure if it would be possible to mount the screen from the ceiling (nor do I have any experience on how to do that).

Comment: if the chimneys wall is from brick/masonry then it should be at least and I mean ATLEAST 15cm thick.. that's usually 2 courses thick. You should be fine going into that with heavy duty robolts.. maybe an extra to to support leverage weight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get yourself some [shelf brackets](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001OBJ5AK) and attach them to your wall into studs. Work out the spacing of the brackets for your screen. The brackets look like this:

[image]

Attach some 3/4" hardwood (oak, maple, etc.) planks to it to make a nice looking shelf. Attach the screen underneath the shelves which should conceal the hanging brackets and give you the clearance away from the wall you're looking for. You may want to drill a hole through the shelves and attach the screen using bolts and nuts instead of screwing directly into the wood shelves. You can also use the shelf to display some cool movie knickknacks.

You could also build something fancy using a French Cleat if you have the skills and tools.

Comment: is that going to hold 13kb...erhm 30lbs.. ?  ahh it should..

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a great idea that I had not considered.

Comment: @RobRolnick, did you hang the screen? Which model did you end up choosing? What's your experience with ripples on the surface of the screen? I am considering a similar model but am worried about ripples, so I may decide to go with a permanently mounted screen (SilverTicket).